# C#, WinForms, Cворачивается группа c елементами

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите, как на WinForms сделать раскрывающуюся группу с элементами (textBox например) внутри, как здесь на картинке или какой контрол можна использовать или создать свой? Сейчас эти элементы у меня в tabControl но хочется изящнее

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Родного такого контрола нет. А вообще такой компонент обычно называется Accordion. Поиск по этому названию выдает немало реализаций.

Comment: спасибо огромное за направление в правильную сторону Alexander Petrovб, вот похожая статья https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303195/winforms-accordion

Comment: В wpf есть такой штатный компонент – Expander